# Material-UI TextField select menu stays fixed on scroll

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When scrolling with TextField menu open, menu stays in fixed position on the page.
How to make menu adjust to TextField element and follow it on scroll?

```
<TextField
    value={1}
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    select
    SelectProps={{
        MenuProps: {
            disableScrollLock: true,
        },
    }}
>
    {[...new Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={index}>
            {index}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</TextField>
```

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-violet-wpfhc4?file=/src/App.js)